# SQL - Conditions between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, case, active-users

I have a table with 3 columns: `user_id`, `start_date`, `cancellation_date`

[image: Table]

I would like to get 4 columns of:
`Date`, `Number of Active Users`, `Number of Users Who Canceled`, `Cancellation Rate`

Any ideas on how to write a query of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @DavidRibert . .. I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  In addition to sample data, show the desired results.  Be quite clear on how each column is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to measure new users, cancelled users, active users:

```
SELECT  calendar_date,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users AS usr WHERE cal.calendar_date BETWEEN usr.start_date AND IFNULL(usr.cancellation_date, '3000-01-01')) AS active_users,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users AS usr WHERE usr.start_date = cal.calendar_date) AS new_users,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users AS usr WHERE usr.cancellation_date = cal.calendar_date) AS users_cancelled
FROM    my_calendar AS  cal
```

(assuming you have table "my_calendar" which contains all dates)

Answer (score 0):

If we define active user as cancellation_date is null, the query will be like this;

```
SELECT 
( SELECT CURDATE() ) AS `DATE`,
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE cancellation_date IS NULL) AS `Number of active users`,
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE cancellation_date IS NOT NULL) AS `number of users who cancelled`,
( SELECT `number of users who cancelled` / (`Number of active users` + `number of users who cancelled`)) AS `cancellation rate`
```

Tested on MySQL 8, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6QPLn2C79rnzrfN71i1GMV/0

Comment: Hi, thank you! in this query, I will get only the current date. any ideas on how can I get a list of all the dates? (Let's say from 1/1/2020)